# How to update indicator info for XLPagerTabStrip in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I want to update my indicator info on some events happening in the child view controllers. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if let pagerTabStrip = self.parent as? ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {
    pagerTabStrip.buttonBarView.reloadData()
}
```

For anybody looking for a solution to this.
Please refer [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/issues/412#issuecomment-358628136).

Comment: Updates the value. Worked for me for values.